# How to find the basis of a matrix by using Gauss-Elliminaton?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, gaussian-elimination

I confuse that, This is my calculating process,

Where i do the mistake in this process?

I hope to understand this error.

[image]

Comment: yours is correct, though the vector (0, 0, 2) could be replaced with (0, 0, 1).

Comment: But it is not clear how $0,1,2$ can be reached. But since the ranks coincide, both solutions should be right.

Comment: if you divide row 3 by 2, you get [0,0,1], adding this to row 2 gives you [0,2,4]. Dividing this by 2 gives you [0,1,2]. Both are correct though.

Comment: OK, this is the way ...